# How to List All Possible Combination of a Number in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

in cell "A1" = 123 and "A2" = 456.

May I know how can I show all the possible combination so that it will look like this:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
456
465
546
564
645
654
```

I tried to search online but cannot find any solution. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below to generate all permutations of the digits in the string.

```
Sub GetPermutation(x As String, y As String, ByRef CurrentRow As Double)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    j = Len(y)
    If j < 2 Then
        Cells(CurrentRow, 1) = x & y
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Else
        For i = 1 To j
            Call GetPermutation(x + Mid(y, i, 1), _
            Left(y, i - 1) + Right(y, j - i), CurrentRow)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

For your example you could do:

```
CurrentRow = 2
Call GetPermutation("",Range("A1").value,CurrentRow)
```

Comment: If you are planning on using this on large scale problems such as permutations of 9 digits, you shouldn't use Excel. I would suggest something like Python instead.